# Graphics driver issues with Ubuntu Gnome edition 15.10

Tags: nvidia, 15.10, multiple-monitors, visual-artifacts

I have an ASUS N55S notebook with nVidia Geforce GT555m chipset. In addition to the notebook display, I have an external Samsung monitor that is connected via HDMI. Since the update from Ubuntu Gnome edition 15.04 to Ubuntu Gnome edition 15.10, I have the following graphics driver issues:

**Issues with the Nouveau driver:**

1. Occasional mouse pointer artifacts, especially (but not exclusively) when the mouse pointer is over the title bar of the desktop, the system tray, scrollbars, menues, etc.
2. I want to use the external monitor as the main display. When I change that in the "Displays" settings and press apply, the dialog asking if I want to keep the changes appears, but I cannot click any button. It looks like the screen is frozen, even the counter counting down the seconds until the changes are reverted is frozen. I can still move the mouse, but I cannot click on anything.

Since I had the artifacts issue with the Nouveau driver in previous Ubuntu releases too, I always went with the nVidia driver which fixed this issue. The problem with 15.10 is, that the nVidia driver is also not working.

**Issues with the nVidia driver:**

When the nVidia driver is installed, the graphical user interface does not start at boot and I end up with a hires command-line login prompt that is constantly flickering. Keyboard presses are ignored most of the time, so I cannot really login to the system. In addition to the latest nVidia driver that comes with Ubuntu 15.10, I have also added the nVidia driver PPA and installed the 355.11 driver, but the result was same.

I have also tried to do a clean install with the Ubuntu Gnome edition live CD, but the installer freezes at boot.

Any ideas how I can solve these issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Instructions for the clean installation of Ubuntu** :

Boot from the Ubuntu GNOME installation media.

When the **boot menu** appears : Highlight **Try Ubuntu without installing** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

When having entered the desktop start the installation process, once completed restart the PC.

When the **GRUB boot menu** appears : Highlight the **Ubuntu menu entry** and  press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add the `nouveau.modeset=0` parameter to the end of the linux line ... Then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.

Now install the new drivers and NVIDIA Optimus support.

When the login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.

Enter your user name and password and then execute:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-355 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case you have to adjust which card to use in BIOS select **NVIDIA** or  **switchable graphics mode**.
Open **NVIDIA X Server Settings** -> **Prime Profiles** to switch between the intel and NVIDIA GPUs.

Comment: Thank's to your instructions I could run the live-CD installer and the clean install solved the issue with the nvidia driver.

Comment: What do you mean by "install the NVIDIA drivers and Optimus support"?

Comment: @AshharHasan : Here is the installation commands explanation -> nvidia-355 = NVIDIA graphics drivers | nvidia-prime = NVIDIA Optimus support - the solution to switch between the intel and NVIDIA graphics :)